# Borland C++ 3.1 and TASM - assembler undefined symbol error

Tags: assembly, tasm, 16-bit

I am doing some retro 16bit computing using Borland C++ 3.1 (and TASM) in Dosbox.

I am reading a book by Christopher Lampton - Gardens of Imagination (1994) - and I lost the floppy disk that came with the book.

Which means that I have to write code off of pages.
Has been a smooth ride so far.

Now, I am going to add optimization to my little raycaster, and I added `fixmul`, `fixdiv` and `drawwall` and it all worked fine.

All hell broke lose upon adding the `drawfloorrow` function.. :(

TASM complains that `width`, `lightindex`, `xincrement`, etc are undefined symbols.
That's odd, because with my extremely limited assembly knowledge: am I not defining them as symbols?

I am confused.

And I know next to nothing about assembly, so if there are a couple of veteran assembly programmers out there that can spot my mistake(s), I would be happy. :)

```
.MODEL  large
.CODE
.386
PUBLIC  _fixmul,_fixdiv,_drawwall
PUBLIC  _drawfloorrow

_fixmul     PROC
    ARG arg1:DWORD, arg2:DWORD
    push    bp          ; set up BP register
    mov     bp, sp
    mov     eax, arg1   ; get first argument into EAX
    imul    arg2        ; multiply it by second argument
    shrd    eax,edx,16  ; shift high and low bytes into DX:AX
    pop     bp
    ret
_fixmul     ENDP

_fixdiv     PROC
    ARG numer:DWORD, denom:DWORD
    push    bp          ; set up BP register
    mov     bp,sp
    mov     eax,numer   ; put dividend into EAX
    mov     edx,eax     ; copy it into EDX
    sar     edx,16      ; shift high 16 bits of EDX back into EAX
    shl     eax,16      ; shift low 16 bits of EAX into high 16 bits
    idiv    denom       ; divide by divisor
    shld    edx,eax,16  ; get result
    pop     bp
    ret
_fixdiv     ENDP

COLUMNLOOP  MACRO
    shld    edi,edx,16          ; move integral portion of bitmap
                                ; pointer into DI
    mov     al,es:[ebx + eax]   ; get lightsourced color
    mov     gs:[si],al          ; copy pixel color to screen column
    sub     edx,ecx             ; add increment to bitmap pointer
    sub     si,bp               ; point to next pixel in wall column
ENDM


_drawwall   PROC
    ARG screenptr:DWORD, bitmapptr:DWORD, height:WORD, increment:DWORD, litelevel:DWORD
    push    bp                  ; save BP
    mov     bp,sp               ; set up stack pointer
    mov     bx,height           ; get height in BX
    mov     ax,200              ; calculate number of pixels to skip
    sub     ax,bx               ; leave result in AX
    mov     ecx,increment       ; get increment in ECX
    lgs     si,screenptr        ; get screen index in GS:SI
    lfs     di,bitmapptr        ; get pointer to bitmap in FS:DI
    mov     ebx,0               ; clear out EBX
    les     bx,litelevel        ; get lightsource table addr in BX
    mov     dx,di               ; copy increment in DX
    shl     edx,16              ; reverse the bytes
    imul    ax,21               ; calculate jump address
    mov     di,offset walloop   ; add start of loop....
    add     di,ax               ; ...to offset in loop
    mov     bp,320              ; store constant in BP
    xor     eax,eax             ; clear out EAX
    jmp     di                  ; jump unto unrolled loop
walloop:
    REPT    200                 ; repeat macro 200 times
        COLUMNLOOP
    ENDM
    pop     bp                  ; restore BP
    ret
_drawwall   ENDP

FLOORLOOP   MACRO   REP
    LOCAL   SKIPPIXEL
    lgs     bx,[botptr]         ; get pointer to BOTS array
    mov     al,gs:[bx]          ; get current bottom position
    mov     bx,[rownum]         ; get current row number
    cmp     al,bl               ; compare the two
    ja      SKIPPIXEL           ; jump if floor pixel behind the wall
    shld    edi,edx,10          ; (int)x / 64
    shld    ebx,ecx,10          ; (int)y / 64
    and     ebx,15              ; clear out junk in EBX
    shl     ebx,4               ; multiply y * 16
    and     edi,15              ; clear out junk in EDI
    add     bx,di               ; BX = (int)y / 64 * 16 + (int)x / 64
    mov     al,es:[ebp + ebx]   ; get tile number in AL
    lgs     bx,[texture]        ; point GS:BX at texture list
    mov     edi,gs:[ebx + (eax * 4)]    ; get pointer to texture map
    mov     [textureptr],edi    ; save texturemap pointer
    shld    edi,ecx,16          ; calculate (int)y % 64 * 320 + x % 64
    shld    ebx,edx,16
    and     edi,63
    and     ebx,63
    imul    di,320
    add     di,bx
    lgs     bx,[textureptr]     ; get pointer to texture
    mov     al,gs:[bx + di]     ; get pixel color
    lgs     bx,[lightIndex]     ; point to lightsource table
    mov     al,gs:[ebx + eax]   ; get lightsourced color
    mov     fs:[si + rep],al    ; put it on screen
SKIPPIXEL:
    add     dword ptr [botptr],1    ; advance bottom pointer
    add     ecx,[yincrement]    ; add increments to get
    add     edx,[xincrement]    ; next pixel coordinate
ENDM

_drawfloorrow   PROC
    ARG row:WORD,screenptr:DWORD,texturelist:DWORD,floormap:DWORD,litelevel:DWORD,bots:DWORD,xinc:DWORD,yinc:DWORD,x:DWORD,y:DWORD,w:WORD
    push    bp              ; save BP
    mov     bp,sp           ; set up stack pointer
    mov     bx,w            ; move parameters into memory variables
    mov     [width],bx
    mov     ebx,litelevel
    mov     [lightindex],ebx
    mov     bx,row
    mov     [rownum],bx
    mov     [colnum],0
    mov     ecx,y
    mov     edx,x
    lfs     si,screenptr
    mov     ebx,xinc
    mov     [xincrement],ebx
    mov     ebx,texturelist
    mov     [texture],ebx
    mov     ebx,bots
    mov     [botptr],ebx
    les     bp,floormap
    xor     eax,eax         ; clear the EAX register

floor:
    FLOORLOOP 0         ; unroll FLOORLOOP 8 times
    FLOORLOOP 1
    FLOORLOOP 2
    FLOORLOOP 3
    FLOORLOOP 4
    FLOORLOOP 5
    FLOORLOOP 6
    FLOORLOOP 7
    add     si,8            ; advance screen pointers
    add     [colnum],8      ; increase column count
    mov     bx,[colnum]     ; have we covered entire viewport?
    cmp     bx,[width]
    jb      floor           ; if not, do it again

    pop     bp              ; else return to caller
    ret
_drawfloorrow   ENDP

END
```

Errors start to appear with this code:

```
mov     [width],bx
```

**Disclaimer**: Someone in the comments said that I do not know what a symbol is. Of course I do. :)
I just don't know how to create them in assembly.
I create symbols all the time in C and C++, and other languages.

EDIT:

Could it be that the ASM source code file is missing a data segment?

Gist here : [OPTI.ASM](https://gist.github.com/jacmoe/3a267787c9d8810e04821093bf4908ce)

Comment: I don't see anywhere in your code where `width` is defined as a symbol.

Comment: That's true. I believe that `mov [width],bx` is supposed to store what's in bx into 'width'  and thus create a new symbol?

Comment: You don't seem to know what a symbol is.

Comment: That instruction requires that `width` be defined somewhere else so it knows where it's supposed to be located. That definition would also normally allocate space somewhere for `width`.

Comment: No. It doesn't  create a new symbol/memory area and hence it creates this error...

Comment: A simple fix for that one error would be to delete that instruction and the previous `mov bx, w` instruction. Then change the later `cmp bx,[width]` to `cmp bx, w`. In other words use the argument `w` directly rather than copying it to a non-existing memory location.

Comment: Oops... no, that won't work because the code later changes BP, which is needed to access the argument `w`.

Comment: Strange that code that doesn't really work made it into the book.

Comment: Happens all the time unfortunately. It's actually more strange for code in a book to not have errors.

Comment: Since the book came out in 1994, it's a bit late to ask for errata :p

Comment: For what its worth I don't think "ray casting" is the way to go when writing a 3D maze game in 1994. While Wolfenstien 3D went that route in 1992, Ultima Underworld used more or less standard texture mapping techniques a couple months earlier. Doom in 1993 used texture mapping, though with a lot of hacks and limitations for increased speed.

Comment: Raycasting was indeed the way to go, because nobody knew how Id did it yet. I've seen many raycasters from 1996/1997, but they all use Watcom.

Comment: Some of those symbols need to be defined with DD instead of DW or DB, see rkhb's answer. Also note that `yincrement` isn't initialized by your code anywhere.

Comment: @RossRidge what is the difference between DD, DW and DB ? I am searching around the interwebs for a TASM tutorial, but can't find any that explains that basic fact.

Comment: yincrement gets a 0 (zero) AFAIK.

Comment: None of that was a secret in 1994. People were creating level editors and custom WADs for Doom in 1994, which isn't possible if you don't know the particular way Doom renders levels. If you asked me in 1994 I could've told you that Ultima Underworld used standard texture mapping and the simple hack they used to make that work on PCs of the era (use a divide approximation for the perspective divide). By 1996 Quake had come out and was using pretty much bog standard texture mapping, anyone using "ray-casting" then was way behind the times.

Comment: DD means "define DWORD", DW means "define WORD" and DB means "define BYTE". They allocate that much memory (4, 2, and 1 bytes respectively) in the current section. If there's a symbol given before it then that symbol is located at the address allocate and that symbol gets the corresponding type.

Comment: @RossRidge could you post an answer so that I can give you points for your hints about yincrement not defined and DD/DW/DB and that they need to be defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a library which has to be linked together with other libraries and the main program. I guess the missing symbols are defined in another module. EXTRN declares an external symbol.

Add

```
EXTRN width:word, rownum:word, colnum:word, xincrement:dword, yincrement:dword, texture:dword, textureptr:dword, lightindex:dword, botptr:dword
```

to the beginning of the source code and you get no more errors. Then you have to find out where the symbols reside.

Comment: Thanks for strong hints!

Comment: They are used internally, and the problem was (I believe) that the ASM source file needed a DATA segment.

Comment: @jacmoe: The .DATA segment mustn't exist in every source file. It can be in another module. All .DATA segments will be linked together to a single .DATA segment. If you define the symbols here, you can get errors in the link stage for redefining symbols. However, this is speculative. I don't know the book.

Comment: Duly noted - thanks! :) Only one module, for now - using inline ASM for VGA, etc.

Comment: @jacmo: please think "needn't" when you see the typical German error "mustn't". Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the ASM source file needs a DATA segment, so - with good help from **RossRidge** and **rkhb** - here is an excerpt from the top of the file with the missing data section:

```
        .MODEL  large
        .DATA
        yincrement  dd  0
        .DATA?
        wwidth  dw  ?
        lightindex  dd  ?
        rownum  dw  ?
        colnum  dw  ?
        xincrement  dd  ?
        texture     dd  ?
        botptr      dd  ?
        textureptr  dd  ?

        .CODE
        .386
        PUBLIC  _fixmul,_fixdiv,_drawwall
        PUBLIC  _drawfloorrow

_fixmul     PROC
    ARG arg1:DWORD, arg2:DWORD
[...]
```